# Simple SignalR Chat

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I followed the documentation at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs to create a simple chat application using SignalR Hubs.

I can't get it to work and don't understand what I'm doing wrong?

I keep getting the following error:

**SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()**

Hub class:

```
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        Clients.addMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Proxy created on the fly
            var chat = $.connection.chat;

            // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it
            chat.addMessage = function (message) {
                $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
            };

            $("#broadcast").click(function () {
                // Call the chat method on the server
                chat.send($('#msg').val())
            .done(function () {
                console.log('Success!');
            })
            .fail(function (e) {
                console.warn(e);
            });
            });

            // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();


        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="msg" />
        <input type="button" id="broadcast" value="broadcast" />
        <ul id="messages">
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Packages:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.0.8" />
  <package id="SignalR.Server" version="0.4.0.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <package id="SignalR.Hosting.AspNet" version="0.4.0.0" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.6.4" />
  <package id="SignalR.Js" version="0.4.0.1" />
  <package id="SignalR" version="0.4.0" />
  <package id="jQuery.Color" version="1.0" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked in the developer tools for your browser to see if there are any errors?

It's possible that SignalR is unable to start up on the client due to getting an error (e.g. 500) when trying to connect to the server.

Comment: Yes, I'm debugging in IE9 using the developer tools. The only error I get is when I click the #Broadcast button and try invoke chat.send

Comment: Just had another check, I'm getting a 500 status code for URL 
/signalr/negotiate

Comment: @samandmoore, "SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()"

Comment: @sarah did you make a new `Project` or a new `Website`? It might not work as a `Website`. I just created a new `Project` with your above paste and it works perfectly.

Comment: @samandmoore yes I'm creating a Project, tried both mvc and webforms. The server error I'm getting for URL /signalr/negotiate is "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies."  Nuget is installing Newtonsoft.Json version=4.0.8 but SignalR is looking for version 4.0.7.0. Weird...

Comment: Not weird, expected. Update your version of nuget and it'll work just fine. Since you're already broken you can run the Add-BindingRedirect command from the Package Manager Console.